# how can I get these if statements working

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, nested

i am trying to get my data from the database and wrap it with html tags. here is the working code so far:

```
function homethumb(){ $this->count; $i = 0;
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($this->result))
   {
      $this->count++; $i++;
      if($i == 1){echo '<div class="gal1">';}
      echo '<a href="portfolio.php?id=' . $row->id . '"> <div class="gal"><img src="img/' . $row->thumb2 . '.jpg"></div></a>';
      if($i == 2){
      echo '</div> <!-- gal1 -->';
      $i=0;
      } 
   }
}
```

Here I am getting everything from the database (Select * from portfolio), but in the portfolio I have, websites, demos and graphics; so I wanted to get only the data where category = "web" from the above code, so I tried this:

```
function homethumb(){ $this->count; $i = 0;
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($this->result))
   {
      if($row->category = "web"){
               $this->count++; $i++;
         if($i == 1){echo '<div class="gal1">';}
         echo '<a href="portfolio.php?id=' . $row->id . '"> <div class="gal"><img src="img/' . $row->thumb2 . '.jpg"></div></a>';
         if($i == 2){
         echo '</div> <!-- gal1 -->';
         $i=0;
         } 
      }
   }
}
```

now the nested if statements do not generate the divs I need, how can I get this working

thanks for your help

Comment: Are you filtering your `thumb2` when it is input to prevent [Cross-site scripting flaws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)?

Comment: @sarnold no, how would I do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see your SQL based on your question, but you could just modify your SELECT query to include `WHERE category="web"`

This way, you're only selecting the rows you **need**, instead of looping over **every** row in that table.

Additionally, it appears that you're using assignment `=` instead of comparison `==` for your `if` statement.

Comment: the '=' was a typo error, and the where filter is something that I really did not want to do in this case as, it would conflict with other queries

Comment: So did fixing the typo correct your issue?  Or after fixing that in your code, are you still not getting the result you want?

Comment: I fixed the typo, and I changed the code to "where category="

Answer (score 2):

Do you just need to have `==` instead of `=`?

```
if($row->category == "web"){
```

But it would be best to restrict the query to the results you need at the database level, unless you need the other rows for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

1)You missed an equal sign:

`if($row->category = "web")` => `if($row->category == "web")`

Or better yet

`if($row->category === "web")`

2)If you want to only get fields with a specific `category` field, you can simply change your query:

`[rest of your query] WHERE category="web"`

Comment: I added them, above was a typo error, but i still get the same problem and I am using one Select query for everything, so whilst a where filter would satisfy this problem, it would brake others

Answer (score 0):

OK, it should go like this, assuming the fields are sorted as follows

ID, category, website, thumb2, demo, graphics

```
function homethumb(){ $this->count; $i = 0;
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($this->result))
   {
      if($row[1] == "web"){
               $this->count++; $i++;
         if($i == 1){echo '<div class="gal1">';}
         echo '<a href="portfolio.php?id=' . $row[0] . '"> <div class="gal"><img src="img/' . $row[3] . '.jpg"></div></a>';
         if($i == 2){
         echo '</div> <!-- gal1 -->';
         $i=0;
         } 
      }
   }
}
```

and there is no need for the nested if, you can just use it in one line as follows:

```
if($row[1] = "web")
{
    echo '<div class="gal1">';
    echo '<a href="portfolio.php?id=' . $row[0] . '"> <div class="gal"><img src="img/' . $row[3] . '.jpg"></div></a>';
    echo '</div> <!-- gal1 -->';
}
```

Comment: i get this error -  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Answer (score 0):

1)  Change your query to contain a WHERE category="web" clause

2)  You have an assignment operator in your if clause (=), when you need an equality operator (==)